# alias with space in columns using linq and gridview to export excel

Tags: linq, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, alias

I need to export Excel and I'm using MVC4

This is my code

```
var co = from c in context.AN_COMPANY
    orderby c.COMPANY_DESCR
    select c;

List<AN_COMPANY_EXT> societa_list = new List<AN_COMPANY_EXT>();

foreach (var o in co)
{
    AN_COMPANY_EXT c_ex = new AN_COMPANY_EXT(o);
    societa_list.Add(c_ex);
}

GridView gv = new GridView();

gv.DataSource = (from d in societa_list
    select new { Codice = d.ID_COMPANY, Descrizione = d.COMPANY_DESCR, SAP_Alias = d.COMPANY_SAP_ALIAS, Booking_Company = d.IS_BOOKING_COMPANY });
gv.DataBind();

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AnagraficaSocieta.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

How can I set column name with a space, for example "SAP ALIAS" instead of SAP_ALIAS?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass a header with a space in it.  something you might try is to loop through the header row after it is created and replace the _ with a space.

Comment: ok, i've tried in this way and it seems to work   int header_cell = gv.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < header_cell; i++)
                {
                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace("_", " ");
                }

Comment: glad you got it working.  Been thinking about this.  did you try adding a quotes around the header fields?  In the past I have used quotes for exporting to a .csv which helped it ignore comma's that were throwing off the columns.